# Python call row of dataframe by a value within the row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset of 16 columns x 850 rows. If the dataset is set up like the following for example:

```
Name   Age   Height   Weight  
John   17    6'0"     160  
Sarah  25    5'3"     120  
James  51    5'10"    180
```

I would like to be able to call any name, and return the entire row of data.

ie: "John" returns:

```
Name   Age   Height   Weight  
John   17    6'0"     160
```

I've read the excel file with `grid_notes = pd.read_excel(grid_notes_path)` to make it a data frame.

Comment: Also, this is my first post, so please let me know if I need to change anything moving forward!

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `Name` as index:

```
grid_notes = pd.read_excel(grid_notes_path, index_col=['Name'])
```

then you can do:

```
grid_notes.loc['John']
```

Or, you can leave your dataframe as is now, and use boolean indexing:

```
grid_notes[grid_notes['Name'] == 'John']
```

but that'll be slightly slower.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using your last method.